# objc[13983]: Class CSAudioFileManager is implemented in both (yada yada) One of which will be undefined

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting this error like a million times in my debugger for slightly different things and I have no idea why:

> objc[13983]: Class CSAudioFileManager is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x136100210) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x134fca990). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Any idea what this is, if anything's wrong, and if so how to fix it? Thanks.  (app still working fine by the way so I don't know what this is).

Comment: The [same question is asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62970821/xcode-12-beta-and-ios-14-weird-console-logs-objc5551-class-is-implement)
Unfortunately no solution, yet - only a lot of people like you and me having the same issue.

Comment: I faced this issue when Mac auto update installed Xcode 12.5.1 over 12.5 automatically and then I was seeing all these errors in the console when using the simulator. On Actual device seems to be normal. In the end, I removed Xcode entirely and reinstalled it and it built up the simulator folders and (as of now) it seems to be gone

Comment: I had same problem, also app didn't start when building iOS 14.3 devices, solved the issue by running/building my app on iOS 15 devices.